# Can skin be removed and replaced so that it maintains its original cellular structure?

Tags: human-biology, skin, injury, surgery

The cells in our body that form tissue, such as our skin, are interconnected. I would think that cutting out tissue or trying to repair/replace it, as is done in surgery, or after an injury, could not be accomplished without damaging this network and creating irreparable damage.

Am I mistaken and is it possible to remove and replace skin, close a wound without damaging the underlying cellular structure and having scar tissue form?

When it is healing, is the tissue that is healing in some way weaker than the tissue that remained intact, say just beyond the margin of the wound?

If someone has surgery, can their skin be repaired completely with the proper amount of healing time?

Answer (score 4):

As pertains to skin, no. As pertains to your other fears, that's a different question.

Every cut that extends into the dermis significantly (and to remove skin, it must include the dermis) will leave a scar behind.

[image]

Cuts that extend only very superficially into the dermis may hit some capillaries and bleed, but these will usually not bleed much, and can heal "seamlessly". But anything that extends deeper will bleed more. Those are the cuts that often get stitches if they are long enough, won't stop bleeding, etc.

Lifting and replacing a piece of skin would necessitate the damage of many cells and the destruction of a lot of fine blood vessels, but even with the best microsurgical techniques, a scar will form. The best techniques combined with the best pre- and post-surgical care will only minimize scar formation; it can't be eliminated.

> In skin, the process of wound repair can be generalized into three cascading phases each with characteristic cellular events: 1) inflammation; 2) fibroplasia or proliferative phase; and 3) **scar formation**.

<sub>[Wound Healing in Development](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3678537/)</sub>

Comment: I have the honor :-) congrats on 10k :-D